# react native e-library app error-failed to resolve dependency 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am in the middle of creating a simple library app. Here, I am trying to use firestore database in firebase console. I am coding this on the expo snack editor. It does not work.
here is a screenshot of the error in the snack editor:
[image: error]

These 2 lines are definitely causing the error:

```js
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
```

PS this is the firebase version 9 sdk

this is my package.json in snack editor:
[image: package.json]

**EDIT: I forgot to mention that this exact code on snack is working fine in VS Code locally.**
to get a working example of code locally:
go to this link: https://snack.expo.dev/@rpshende/e-library-app

Then,

1. Extract the folder
2. cd to the folder in terminal
3. run command 'npm install'
4. then run command 'expo start'(make sure expo cli is installed for this to work!)
5. when the expo developer tools are fired up, press 'W' on the terminal to open project in a web browser

EDIT: i think this is a problem with the snack editor itself.....

Answer (score 3):

As @whitehatcoder says, in the expo bubble editor there are version differences. Firebase should have been on version 8 instead of 9.

I add that you try this
{
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "8.8.1"
}
}

Comment: If I am not mistaken (please correct me) the snack editor only allows to use firebase 8.

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase v9 is Different**

try this

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider , signInWithPopup, } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaTyD2Jp9aB7ycUbW1z8QyPLmD111rHezHcOw",
  authDomain: "delete-project-c7021.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "delete-project-c7021",
  storageBucket: "delete-project-c7021.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "688102987186",
  appId: "1:688102987186:web:e27537ggg7abc2b86b982b"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth();
```

Comment: will definitely try this later

Comment: still doesn't work, having the same error

Comment: Has nothing to do with the code. It can't install a dependency. Did you find a solution?

Comment: found a solution

Comment: in the expo snack editor there are version differences. firebase needed to be at version 8 instead of 9